# find and replace the word on a string based on the condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

hello dear helpful ppl at stackoverflow ,

I have couple questions about manipulating a `string` in `python` ,

**first question:-**

if I have a `string` like :

```
'What's the use?'
```

and I want to locate the first letter after `'the'`

like (What's the use?) the letter is `u`

how I could do it in the best way possible ?

**second question:-**

if I want to change something on this string based on the first letter i found in the (First question)
how I could do it ?

and thanks for helping !

Comment: With a regex: [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mQvdya/1) To replace: [demo](https://regex101.com/r/ojL2AM/1)

Comment: What kind of change on the string do you mean? It's not possible to change a string in place. But you can create a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regex replacement to remove all content up and including the first `the` (along with any following whitespace).  Then, just access the first character from that output.

```py
inp = 'What''s the use?'
inp = re.sub(r'^.*?\bthe\b\s*', '', inp)
print("First character after first 'the' is: " + inp[0])
```

This prints:

```
First character after first 'the' is: u
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the index of 'u' by using the [str.index()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.index) method. Then you can extract string before and after using [slice operation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations).

```py
s = "What's the use?"
character_index = s.lower().index('the ') + 4
print(character_index)
# 11
print(s[:character_index] + '*' + s[character_index+1:])
# What's the *se?
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `re` take:

```
import re

sample = "What is the use?"
pattern = r"""
    (?<=\bthe\b)    # look-behind to ensure 'the' is there.  This is non-capturing.
    \s+             # one or more whitespace characters
    (\w)            # Only one alphanumeric or underscore character
"""

# re.X is for verbose, which handles multi-line patterns
m = re.search(pattern, sample, flags = re.X).groups(1)
if not m is None:
    print(f"First character after first 'the' is: {m[0]}")
```